# dns.resolve result into a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, dns, dnspython

Ive created a simple dns.query function, I am attempting to add the results into a list or potentially a dictionary. However I cant work out how to achieve it, I have tried list.append(subdomain, item), ive tried using the join function and I have tried to use the update function respectably.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

**ORIGINAL**

```
def get_brutes(subdomain):
    targets = []
    try:
        myResolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
        myResolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']
        myAnswers = myResolver.query(subdomain)
        for item in myAnswers.rrset:
            targets.append(subdomain,item)  

    except Exception as e:
        pass
    return targets
```

**FIX**

```
def get_brutes(subdomain):
    targets = []
    try:
        myResolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
        myResolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']
        myAnswers = myResolver.query(subdomain)
        for item in myAnswers.rrset:
            targets.append(subdomain + ' ' + str(item))

    except Exception as e:
        pass
    return targets
```

Comment: So, are you getting an error, or what?

Comment: apologies no i just get blank results

Comment: I guess you wouldn't see any errors because you're silently `pass`ing whenever one occurs. If you delete the `try` and `except`, do you get any errors?

Comment: I have just tried 'targets.append(subdomain + ' ' + str(item))' and that seems to have worked. I printed e and found a helpful error, imagine that :)

Comment: is there a better way to achieve what i am after?

Comment: @iNoob: The "better way" is to never swallow exceptions like this unless you're entirely certain of what's going to be raised and why it's safe to continue.

Comment: Hiya! Originally I knew which error to expect and I didnt care to hear about it. But as the script developed I moved to adding the items to a list rsther than direct print to tidy up results. But yes ill keep it in mind thank you.